# Configurable SSL for angular + spring boot project

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ssl

I am working on project with Spring Boot and Angular 9. Also the project use elastic search for some requests. In this project SSL is applied to all the request of REST as well as elastic search.

To apply SSL within the project, the changes in front end as well as backend is done. Now we want to make configurable SSL, like any flag whether to apply it or not.

For backend I can do with application.yml file by taking any flag and reading it to apply whether SSL to apply or not.

But in front end files mainly : angular.json and package.json have SSL changes, but how to access the values of application.yml flag to identify in front end to apply SSL.

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "webapp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "src/main/webapp/dist",
            "baseHref": "/webapp/",
            "deployUrl": "/webapp/",
            "index": "src/main/webapp/index.html",
            "main": "src/main/webapp/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/main/webapp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/main/webapp/favicon.ico",
              "src/main/webapp/assets",
              "src/main/webapp/robots.txt",
              "src/main/webapp/404.html",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs",
                "output": "/assets/pdfjs"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/main/webapp/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/main/webapp/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/main/webapp/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
              "browserTarget": "webapp:build",
              "ssl": true,
              "sslKey": "C://Workarea//ssl//server.key",
              "sslCert": "C://Workarea//ssl//server.crt"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "webapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "webapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/main/webapp/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/main/webapp/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/main/webapp/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/main/webapp/favicon.ico",
              "src/main/webapp/assets",
              "src/main/webapp/robots.txt",
              "src/main/webapp/404.html",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs",
                "output": "/assets/pdfjs"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "webapp-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "webapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "webapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "webapp",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "808c136f-eea0-4753-a321-b09e208a02c4"
  }
}
```

In **serve** there is ssl, sslKey and sslCert are defind.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "regis-ri-tool",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for Rule Interpretation Tool",
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node build-info.js",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8888 --ssl true --ssl-cert C:\\WorkArea\\ssl\\server.crt --ssl-key C:\\WorkArea\\ssl\\server.key --aot true --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "prebuild": "node build-info.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prebuild:prod": "node build-info.js",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-dynamic-table": "^9.4.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-quill": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^5.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-diff-match-patch": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Similar **start** tag have ssl command in package.json.

part of **application-local.yml** to identify ssl :

```
...............
............

server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
        key-store-password: passw0rd
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-alias: regisri
    servlet:
        context-path: /webapp

............
..............
```

Also have one more file to apply the changes :

**proxy.config.json**

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "https://localhost:8443/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

With **server.ssl.enabled** I can work in backend, but unable to get this in front end package.json, proxy.config.json and angular.json files.

I want configurable to identify ssl changes in these two files, we build the war file so that we need configurable front end as well as backend.

Comment: If i understand correctly your angular is calling more than one backend ... and you want to know if different ones should be ssl. 

if this is correct, i would have one be a primary that you ui knows that calls to find out the others that is configured on the backend.

Comment: @Tim.Burnell Backend is one only, many classes have the changes. I need a way to identify the application should run with ssl or not from front end as well as from backend.

Comment: Isn't it a better statement to say determine if you are running ssl vs if you need to run ssl?  Because you could inspect the url and determine if it is already running ssl.

Comment: That I can check after running the project, I need this before it, as URL will be generated as the build will be created for project. I need the checking before creating build.

Comment: If you rebuild for every environment ... there is environment files you can use: https://angular.io/guide/build
however i lean to being immutable ... so all environment use the same build.